# Shoes Ruby GUI toolkit [error while loading shared libraries: libcairo.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]

Tags: ruby, shoes-4

When I try to run shoes application like **at console: shoes app.rb**
Getting following error on console-

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Shoes....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
/tmp/selfgz5416/shoes-bin: error while loading shared libraries: *libcairo.so.2*: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Have your tried `sudo apt-get install libcairo`?

Comment: Ya but but showing E: Unable to locate package libcairo.

Comment: The try `sudo apt-cache search libcairo`. This library may be contained is another package. You don't use Gnome, do you? I'm almost sure libcairo is part of Gnome by default.

Comment: Yes I dont use Gnome.   But run the command sudo apt-cache search libcairo  but there are many more packages not able to indentify which package I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115582/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-snm-maurya).

Comment: If you succeed in running it, please let me know and then I'll post it as an answer to help other people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: So... have yo manage to solve it?